# Concatenating form input datas with javascript and vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form with vuejs and would like to concatenate on submit the datas from the input fields. I attached a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smr8abfh/4/) where I tried to solve the concat without success.

I have three vue vomponents for the three input field where the first one is a dropdown list where the custom option should be changed to an input text field.

If I'm trying to concat the three datas the js gives me undefined error.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#product_id',
    data: {
        selected: '1',
        options: [
            { text: 'Product 1', id: '1', value: '1' },
            { text: 'Product 2', id: '2', value: '2' },
            { text: 'Product 3', id: '3', value: '3' },
            { text: 'Product 4', id: '4', value: '4' },
            { text: 'Custom', id: '5', value: '' }
        ],
        product_i: '',
        resetKey: 0,
    },
    methods:{
        updateComponent(){
            this.resetKey += 1;
            console.log(this.resetKey);
            console.log('test');
        }
    },
}),

new Vue({
    el: "#product_name",
    data: {
        product_n: '',
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: "#product_price",
    data: {
        product_p: '',
    }
});


function combine_product_datas() {
    var id = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    var name = document.getElementById('input2').value;
    var price = document.getElementById('input3').value;
        document.getElementById('joint').value = id + '.' + name + '/' + price;
        alert(document.getElementById('joint').value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div id="product_id">    
    <div :key="resetKey">
      <small>Product id</small>
      <div v-if="selected != ''">
        <select v-model="selected">
          <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
            {{ option.text }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <br>                      
      <div v-else>
        <input id="id" v-model="product_i" value="" type="text" placeholder="Add your product">
        <button v-on:click="updateComponent">Reset</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>                      
<div id="product_name">
  <div>
    <div>
        <small>Product name</small><br>
        <input id="name" v-model="product_n" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>                      
<div id="product_price">
  <div>
    <div>
      <small>Product price</small><br>
      <input id="price" v-model="product_p" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>                       
<div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" onclick="combine_product_datas();">Combine datas</button>
  </div>
</div>
<br>                      
<input type="hidden" id="joint">
<br>                      
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the code that causes the error

Comment: The code that I'm trying to use it is on the jsfiddle link added before.

Comment: Hey Tikinu, i look at your code, if you just wanna make your v-if / v-else logic work, just remove the:
   <br> 
Tag (from the HTML code) and the logic will work :)

When you use v-if and a v-else-if or a v-else you can't put any code between this codes ok?

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Thank you Julliano, indeed I removed the br tag and this part works. What about the concatenating? Or can you help with the dropdown that if I choose the custom option from the list and the input field appears, I would like to rerender the dropdown component with the reset button. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, I'm not too sure why there needs to be three different Vue instances. You can simply put the whole thing under one  wrapper and use one Vue instance. You can then put the javascript function within the one instance and not have to use document selectors to get the combined value. The revised code is like so (revised js fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/utz2mens/1/)):

```js
new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            selected: '1',
            options: [
                { text: 'Product 1', id: '1', value: '1' },
                { text: 'Product 2', id: '2', value: '2' },
                { text: 'Product 3', id: '3', value: '3' },
                { text: 'Product 4', id: '4', value: '4' },
                { text: 'Custom', id: '5', value: '' }
            ],
            product_i: '',
            resetKey: 0,
            product_n: '',
           product_p: ''
        },
        methods:{
          updateComponent(){
            this.resetKey += 1;
            console.log(this.resetKey);
            console.log('test');
          },
          combineData() {
           const { product_i, product_n, product_p } = this;
            alert(`id: ${product_i}, name: ${product_n}, price: ${product_p}`)
          }
        },
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <small>Product id</small>
  
  <div v-if="selected != ''">
    <select v-model="selected">
      <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
        {{ option.text }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div> 
  
  <div v-else>
    <input id="id" v-model="product_i" value="" type="text" placeholder="Add your product">
    <button @click="updateComponent">Reset</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <small>Product name</small><br>
    <input id="name" v-model="product_n" type="text">
  </div>

  <div>
    <small>Product price</small><br>
    <input id="price" v-model="product_p" type="text">
  </div>            

 <button type="submit" @click="combineData()">Combine data</button>
  <span :value="combined"></span>
                   
  <input type="hidden" id="joint">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Cathy Ha! It works like a charm in this way. You are right the one instance is more handy than I did. Just one little question... How can I pass the value of the product to the alert? If the custom option choosen it passes the content of the input field but the product 1-4 is not. And one litt thing, how can I reset the dropdown element with the reset button from custom input field. I think the key and the updateComponent() should work but now it isnt.

Comment: No problem! So, to answer your questions: 1) to pass the value of the product to the alert, regardless of whether it's custom entered or selected, you can use a computed variable. I'm not too sure if this is the best approach but it works. 2) To reset the form, either wrap the whole code in a <form> element (with ref of whatever you want, I used "form"), and use this.$refs.form.reset() to reset the form - or you can directly reset that variable (product_id = ''). You'll need to add e.preventDefault to prevent the from from submitting. Js fiddle is here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/g5y8twar/1/)

Comment: Great! The reset works but I think I wasn't clear with that. I would like to do with the reset that if clicked the button the dropdown will come back. Not just the input field content will erease. Almost everything works like I want :) Thanks again!

Comment: Oh that's easy! Just say this in the reset function: this.selected = 1